# Can I point my domain and subdomains to AWS hosting without using Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, dns, amazon-route53, a-records

I have some xyz.com domain name (purchased from GoDaddy), and also I need 3 more subdomains like a.xyz.com, b.xyz.com, c.xyz.com.
My question is **without** using AWS Route 53 service(Which is not free) can I point my domain and all subdomains to my AWS ec2 instance folders through A records and configuring .htaccess file ?

Comment: Yes. If your instance has public IP and is publicly accessible, then of course you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to:

- Assign an Elastic IP address to each Amazon EC2 instance (this is a static IP address that will not change)
- Create an `A-Record` in your DNS provider that points to the Elastic IP address

Comment: Yes, I did that. I have one elastic IP which xyz.com is pointing to via A records, and my website files is inside www folder. Now if I create 3 sub folders inside www, and want 3 subdomains to point to them respectively, then how can I do that?

Comment: [VirtualHost Examples - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: I set up 000-default.conf with all the necessary virtual host entries, as well as I tried with different conf files (one per site name) , I also did a2ensite and apache reload but all the sites pointing to same folder content (index.html inside main domain folder). In case of default conf config it picking up the first Vhost entry. In GoDaddy side I mapped (A record) every subdomain to the same elastic IP.

Comment: I suggest you create a new Question focussing on the Virtual Hosts, with full details of what you what you have tried.

Comment: New question link : https://serverfault.com/questions/1020267/subdomain-routing-to-main-domain-in-spite-of-virtual-host-entries-in-aws-withou

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can do this. Route 53 is not a requirement for using AWS services to host your own applications.